# Html formatted text in angular

Tags: html, angular, tinymce

I am new to angular and i am building a blog website. Now, users are provided with the tinymce editor where they can write their content with some predefined format.

[image: User writing the blog]

Now whatever the user writes it gets stored in the database in the following format.

[image: Stored formatted data]

How to render the **same formatted** data in angular front in the exact same format the user had written the blog?
I am unable to process the html tags in the front end for display.
I am using a simple card to display it.
Any other approach i should go for or anything i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone kindly help me to render the same formatted data in angular front in the exact same format the user had written the blog?

If I understood correctly, what you need is innerHTML directive:

```
 <div [innerHTML] = "HTMLasString"></div>
```

Where HTMLasString is the variable that stores HTML content as string. However, if you do not use DomSanitizer and accept user input as it is, your application would have a security vulnerability. Please see: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. I used the dom santizer and [innerHtml] property with a pipe and got the results.
Thanks!